# Snapshot exists but still gives snapshot restore exception elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, restore, snapshot, docker-container

I took an elastic search snapshot (`snapshot_1`) of 4 indices on an EC2 server "A" and copied the data to another EC2 server "B". I updated the path in `elasticsearch.yml` and restarted the ES on server B. (I updated the path and restarted ES before putting the data on that path but the path existed and had the required access).

Upon querying the index file in the snapshot directory I do see that snapshot_1 exists.

```
[elasticsearch@2ed2c2eaa5be uat_dump]$ cat index-0  
{"snapshots":[{"name":"snapshot_1","uuid":"bBc6chD0TCKiQvuqn8gsow","state":1}],"indices":{"my_index_1":{"id":"J-c4ZvN0T02HeyQR8ueyZw","snapshots":["bBc6chD0TCKiQvuqn8gsow"]},"my_index_2":{"id":"ifn1Geq2RHe6wAMuGxpAMw","snapshots":["bBc6chD0TCKiQvuqn8gsow"]},"my_index_3":{"id":"X9dPrB3fRd-WrfNnZN69mQ","snapshots":["bBc6chD0TCKiQvuqn8gsow"]},"my_index_4":{"id":"9OjzD37WRROJFkfu-N7LNg","snapshots":["bBc6chD0TCKiQvuqn8gsow"]}}}
```

But when I am trying to restore the snapshot, I receive the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "snapshot_restore_exception",
        "reason": "[my_backup:snapshot_1] snapshot does not exist"
      }
    ],
    "type": "snapshot_restore_exception",
    "reason": "[my_backup:snapshot_1] snapshot does not exist"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

I do a file `incompatible-snapshots` and its contents are
`{"incompatible-snapshots":[]}`

Any pointers what I could be doing wrong?